# Posting form with ajax to self with no reload and filter back in form data with relevant business names

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm trying to auto submit a form when a user clicks checkbox select (with ajax). I want to prevent the default reload, and then attempt to use the category checkbox values to repopulate the relevant business names, which the user will be able to select to retrieve the full company details.

Quite frankly, it's been driving me a bit mad! I've tried both post and get methods, and 100 other workarounds and I just can't get it to work

If I remove the e.preventDefault(); from my on submit function then the page reloads and I get the correct info across both category and name via $_GET. But problem I have is getting the ajax data passed back to the var_dump($_GET). It always stays empty aside from the URL.

Am I going about this in the wrong way?

Here's my form:

```
<form id="businessSearch" action="" type="get" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
   <div class="col-md-6 business-cat">
      <h2>Business Category</h2>
      <div class="business-inner">
         <input id="category" class="main" <?php if ( !isset($_GET['category']) || ($_GET['category'] == 'All')) { echo 'checked'; } ?> type="checkbox" name="category" value="All" /> All <br>
         <?php foreach($data['businessCats'] as $category) : ?>
         <input id="category"  class="main" <?php if ( isset($_GET['category']) && ($_GET["category"] == $category->BusinessCategory)) { echo 'checked'; } ?> type="checkbox" name="category" value="<?php echo $category->BusinessCategory; ?>"> <?php echo $category->BusinessCategory; ?><br>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 business-name">
      <h2>Company Name</h2>
      <div class="business-inner">
         <?php if( isset($_GET['category']) && ($_GET['category'] != 'All')) : ?>
         <?php foreach($data['businessCategoryListing'] as $businessCatListing) : ?>
         <input id="name"  class="sub" <?php if (isset($_GET["name"]) && ($_GET["name"] == $businessCatListing->company_name)) { echo 'checked'; } ?>  type="checkbox" name="name" value="<?php echo $businessCatListing->company_name; ?>"> <?php echo $businessCatListing->company_name; ?><br>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
         <?php else: ?>
         <?php foreach($data['getAllBusinessListings'] as $getAllBusinessListings) : ?>
         <input id="name" class="sub" <?php if (isset($_GET["name"]) && ($_GET["name"] == $getAllBusinessListings->company_name)) { echo 'checked'; } ?>  type="checkbox" name="name" value="<?php echo $getAllBusinessListings->company_name; ?>"> <?php echo $getAllBusinessListings->company_name; ?><br>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
         <?php endif; ?>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
<?php if ( isset($_GET['category'])  && isset($_GET['name']) )  : ?>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="col-md-12 business-details">
   <h2>Details</h2>
   <div class="business-inner">
      <h2><?php  echo  $data['businessListing']->BusinessName  ?></h2>
      <?php  echo $data['businessListing']->BusinessDescription  . '<br>' . $data['businessListing']->BusinessPhone  . '<br>' . $data['businessListing']->BusinessWebsite  . '<br>' . $data['businessListing']->BusinessAddress1   . '<br>' .  $data['businessListing']->BusinessGrid  . '<br>' ; ?>
   </div>
</div>

 <script>
$('input.main, input.sub').on('change', function() { 
 $('#businessSearch').trigger('submit');
});



$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#businessSearch').on('submit', function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();

       var category = $('#category:checked').val(),
       name = $('#name:checked').val();

$.ajax({
      type: 'get',
      data: { ajax: 1,category: category, name: name},
      success: function(response){
       //$('#response').text('category : ' + response);
      }
     });       
    });
});

</script>
```

I can see my output in the network tab in

[image: network]

I just cannot get it to filter back in the $_GET var_dump and then get the results to update correctly on my page whilst preventing the page reload.

Finally, here is how I'm calling that data from my db

```
 public function getBusinessByCategory() {

      $category = isset($_GET['category']) ? $_GET['category'] : '';

      $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM business_directory WHERE category = :category and publish_status = "live" ORDER BY company_name ASC');
      $this->db->bind(':category', $category);


      $results = $this->db->resultSet();

      return $results;
    }
```

Can anyone give any pointers? I'm really stuck, and my head is about to explode!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want submit a form without reload the page then first do not user button type "submit" in HTML form. Instead of that use normal button and execute your ajax call when user click on that button.

If you will submit button then it will reload the page and it's default behaviour of the submit button type.

Comment: Thanks Dhaval. The submit button is simply or debugging atm for if I need to remove the $('input.main, input.sub').on('change', function() { 
 $('#businessSearch').trigger('submit');
});